# kde-full on Ubuntu

Tags: kde

Since I am really willing to install Krita on Ubuntu, I installed kde-full to be able to do that. When I had to choose the default DM, I chose KDM. When I rebooted, Ubuntu went to tty1. The graphical login screen is gone and I cannot get it back.

I used `dpkg-reconfigure lightdm kdm` and chose lightdm as the default DM; nothing happened. I am still stuck in tty1. I even used the unity-greeter as the default DM, with no success also. I am really frustrated about this.

I like Ubuntu, but I am unable to use Krita on it. The only way I am able to do that is by installing KDE, which gets me into this trouble almost every time I install it. I didn't like Kubuntu, and suffered from WiFi issues with Linux Mint, so I am unable to use each of them, although they both make it possible for me to use Krita.

Keep in mind that I am dual booting Windows 7 with Ubuntu 12.04 on a DELL N5110 laptop which has two graphics cards, an Intel HD one for regular graphics, and an NVIDIA for the high-end graphical applications.

Answer (score 0):

It seemed that the problem was with the `xserver`, so I reinstalled it and it is working well right now, but I have to set `KDM` as the default DM.

I think that `kde-full` was not that much needed. Installing `kdelibs-bin` and `kdelibs5-plugins` was very enough to be able to use Krita. This is what I am going to do the next time I reinstall Ubuntu, at least to avoid the pain that `xserver` caused to me.

Comment: You appear to have two (unregistered) user accounts. To be able to mark your answer as correct, please register and get your account merged. http://askubuntu.com/contact/user-merge